# Minimal sample size for difference-in-difference estimation of causal effect with time-series data

Tags: time-series, sample-size, causality, statistical-power, difference-in-difference

Suppose that Walmart has 1,000 stores. It has a 20% coupon for cereal, and it hypothesizes that the coupon will increase the sales of cereal by 3%.

Walmart wants to put the coupon in $n$ stores on 2023-06-01. Suppose that it has data from 2021-06-01 onward, and that it can install the coupon in those $n$ stores for as long as necessary.

At a significance level of 5%, I want to use [difference-in-difference](https://www.publichealth.columbia.edu/research/population-health-methods/difference-difference-estimation) to estimate the change in sales in the $n$ test stores after 2021-06-01. **What should $n$ be?**